# Why Facebook Graph Api returns "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to list Facebook Page Post in a application. Therefor I use the Facebook Graph API.

I use the following URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/674600022698736/feed?limit=100&fields=name,comments.limit(0).summary(true),permalink_url,shares.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=XXX

I get the response, except for the fields': icon and shares. In the feature I need more, so maybe the problem is with more fields.

De Graph Explorer gives the following response for the fields icon and shared: "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token".
The shares are certainly filled!

See:
[image]

I've made the call with both the user and the page tokens, same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `shares` is a field, not an edge - so using `limit` and `summary` makes no sense here.

Comment: Thanks. But how to access then?

Comment: Looks like this is only returned if there actually are shares for the post.

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: @DannSaHa No. Honestly I didn't try it anymore since then.

Comment: @DannSaHa Check my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

*Although this post is old but has no answer, my answer might help someone*:

If those edges are greyed out, it means you did not give or add those attributes in the access token your calling with. You need to give those permissions.
After adding such permissions for example for your case: `like, comments` you need to regenerate the token by clicking on the **Get Access Token** button and you should see it not grey anymore. Finally, you can **Submit** and get your desired response.

Classic Graph Explorer

> 1.

[image]

> 2

[image]

> 3.

[image]

Better yet, try the new beta Graph Explorer. Has a better GUI for the permissions option.
[Beta Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cbirthday%2Cemail&version=v3.3&classic=0)